# Convert a local resource link (file:///) to an accesible link (http://) in portlet

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hyperlink, liferay

How to convert a directory to a link? While I tried to display image using galleria plugin on liferay, it display nothing. The "Inspect element" mode on Google Chrome shows:

[image]

I get this message on Chrome:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///E:/Liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/Xplor-…et/WEB-INF/files/images/130621_JimmJuli_IO9032193908/IO9032193908_0001.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<div style="background-color: white; padding: 5px; border: 1px black solid;">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Show Images" onclick="dialogImg.show()" />
</div>
<p:dialog header="Images" widgetVar="dialogImg" modal="true" draggable="false" resizable="false" width="540" height="370">
    <p:galleria value="#{viewBacking.images}" var="image" panelWidth="510" panelHeight="310" showCaption="true">  
        <p:graphicImage value="#{image}" title="description"/>  
    </p:galleria>
</p:dialog>
```

The backing bean:

```
public class ViewBacking {
    private List<String> images;
    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public ViewBacking() {
        try {
            getImageList();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getImageList() {
        images = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] imageList = getFileList("//images//imgfolder//"); 
        //--> It will returns: E:\Liferay\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\Xplor-portlet\WEB-INF\files\images\imgfolder\IMAGE_NAME.EXT

        for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
            if (imageList[i].isFile())
                images.add("/files/images/" + imageList[i].getName()); //UPDATE
        }
    }

    //This is how I get a directory path
    public File[] getFileList(String path) {
        File folder = new File(getPath(path));
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        return listOfFiles;
    }
    public String getPath(String fileName) {
        ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        return extContext.getRealPath("//WEB-INF//files//" + fileName);
    }
}
```

As you see on the code above, the image source will filled with something like: `E:\Liferay\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\Xplor-portlet\WEB-INF\files\images\imgfolder\IMAGE_NAME.EXT`, how to make it like `http://localhost:8080/IMAGE_LINK`? Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

I have tried to change the directory become:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- files
 |    |    `-- ...
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- files
 |    |-- images
 |    |    `-- foo.png
 |    |    `-- bar.png
 |    |    `-- baz.png
 :
```

and the galleria still doesn't display the image. While I tried to access it like: `http://localhost:8080/files/images/foo.png`, the browser returns `The requested resource was not found.`. And as you see on the code above, the `images[]` will filled with something like:

```
/files/images/foo.png
/files/images/bar.png
/files/images/baz.png
```

But while I am checking on `view source` mode on Chrome, it returns:

```
/Xplor-portlet/files/images/foo.png
/Xplor-portlet/files/images/bar.png
/Xplor-portlet/files/images/baz.png
```

Comment: Instead of adding imageList[i].getPath() as a image path, you can use `"/Xplor-portlet/WEB-INF/files/images/imgfolder/"+imageList[i].getName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them outside `/WEB-INF` to make them publicly accessible.

E.g.

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- files
 |    |    `-- ...
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- images
 |    |-- foo.png
 |    |-- bar.png
 |    `-- baz.png
 :
```

This way you can access them like

```html
<p:graphicImage value="/images/foo.png" />
<p:graphicImage value="/images/bar.png" />
<p:graphicImage value="/images/baz.png" />
```

Just generate exactly those paths `"/images/foo.png"`, `"/images/bar.png"`, `"/images/baz.png"`, etc instead of local disk file system paths. This makes indeed no sense as the endusers visiting your website doesn't necessarily have those files at exactly the same locations of their own disk file system.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using `ExternalContext#getRealPath()` for this purpose is a poor practice. It may return `null` on some server configurations whereby the WAR file is not been expanded on disk, but instead in memory. Rather use `ExternalContext#getResourcePaths()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Btw, how to prevent the files/folder under `/images` from direct access?

Comment: Blub? You want to show them in public as `<img>` via `<h:graphicImage>`. So they have to be publicly/directly accessible. If you want to prevent them from direct access, then you can't show them as `<img>`. Simple as that.

Comment: I have tried it but still can't display the image. Please see the update above.

Comment: Just do not use FileInputStream. This makes no sense.

Comment: Ahhh... I got it.. Haha, thanks Balus. I missed to add the specific folder to save the image.